# How do I modularize a class that listens to a notification?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to modularize my code, so I can use these modules in many apps of mine. I am trying to make each module independent of each other.

For example: suppose I have a viewController that shows objects to purchase. Suppose I have 3 classes, one that is a module to deal with purchases, a progress bar class and another one that is a spinner. I import all on my viewController. The user taps to purchase something. The purchase class takes control. When the purchase begins, that class fires a notification to start the the spinner. The purchase is downloadable, another notification is fired to start the progress bar and several notifications are fired to update the progress bar. The sales finish. A final notification is fired to stop and hide the spinner and another one to stop and hide the progress bar.

So, you see my pain. The spinner and the progress bar were added to the view controller, but the purchase class was the one firing the notifications to both. So, I have to declare the NSString containing the strings used for all these notifications inside the purchase class, or can simply import the progress bar and the spinner headers into the purchase class. But, as I said, I am trying to make all classes independent. I don't want to have interaction between classes that don't have to work together all the time. Spinner and ProgressBar are classes that can work with any other class that needs them. I don't want to tie the PurchaseClass to them.

I don't want to fire a notification using the string directly on the PurchasesClass, because I may want to change the notification string at some point and will lose track of that direct use. I want a way to create all declarations of notifications a class listens inside that class and I want other classes to know about that before using the class.

I have thought of a central singleton to register all notifications all classes will use in advance and saving that to NSUserDefaults, so every class could read from NSUserDefaults without importing headers from other classes.

What other options do I have here that could be used?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model, the view controller, well… it controls the views. The view controller is the central dispatcher, it should receive the notification from the purchase class and update the views (spinner, progressbar). This is what view controllers do in Apple's MVC.

The purchase class declares the notification constant strings in its header. This design is used all over the iOS SDK.

Comment: OK, I will rethink everything. Thanks.

Comment: Great, good luck. I was trying to think of a good example, but the best one I can come up with uses delegates instead of notifications. For this discussion, the differences between (NS)notification and delegates are unessential, so here goes. A standard way to update a download progress bar would be to have the view controller be notified of the progress by the NSURLConnection. Either directly as the delegate or in whatever way you can come up with. The view controller would the update the progress bar to reflect the change.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using notifications, use blocks. Try something like this in your purchase class:

```
typedef void(^PurchaseManagerBlock) ();

@class ProgressBar, Spinner;

@interface PurchaseManager : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, strong) ProgressBar *progressBar;
@property(nonatomic, strong) Spinner *spinner;
@property(nonatomic, strong) PurchaseManagerBlock startBlock;
@property(nonatomic, strong) PurchaseManagerBlock completionBlock;

@implementation PurchaseManager

-(void)doSomething
{
    self.startBlock();
    //start some asynchronous task
}

-(void)finishSomething
{
   //asynchronous task finished
   self.completionBlock();
}
@end
```

Then in your view controller, you can do things like this:

```
purchaseManager.progressBar = self.progressBar;
purchaseManager.spinner = self.spinner;    
purchaseManager.startBlock = ^{
    progressBar.startProgress;
    spinner.startSpinning;
};

purchaseManager.completionBlock = ^{
    progressBar.stopProgress;
    spinner.stopSpinning;
}
```

Comment: If I understood correcly, I don't see how this will solve the problem. PurchaseClass works asynchronously. To make this work I will have to declare the postNotification to start the spinner in the ViewController inside a block. So I will have to have a bunch of tiny blocks, one to start the spinner, another one to start the progress bar, another one to modify the progress bar, another one to turn off the progress bar and so one. The spinner and the progress bar notifications can happen at different times or one can happen without the other... this is more complex that I thought...

Comment: Add properties of spinner and progress bar to your Purchase class. This way you can modify them at any point.